# Saving a PNG to a variable

Tags: php, php-gd

Is there any way to export the PNG data that's been created using the GD library's imagecreatefrompng directly to a variable, rather than echoing it or saving it to a file?

Comment: My guess is that you can use `ob_start` and family to catch the output when echoing the file

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ob_start` and family to catch the output when you echoing the file. So it would look something like this:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$image_content = ob_get_clean();
```